# Loop that counts unique values in a pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, loops, unique

I am trying to create a `loop` or a more efficient process that can `count` the amount of current values in a `pandas` `df`. At the moment I'm selecting the value I want to perform the function on.

So for the `df` below, I'm trying to determine two `counts`.

1) `['u']` returns the count of the same remaining values left in `['Code', 'Area']`. So how many remaining times the same values occur.

2) `['On']` returns the amount of values that are currently occurring in `['Area']`. It achieves this by parsing through the `df` to see if those values occur again. So it essentially looks into the future to see if those values occur again.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Code' : ['A','A','A','A','B','A','B','A','A','A'],            
    'Area' : ['Home','Work','Shops','Park','Cafe','Home','Cafe','Work','Home','Park'],  
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#Select value
df1 = df[df.Code == 'A'].copy()

df1['u'] = df1[::-1].groupby('Area').Area.cumcount()

ids = [1]
seen = set([df1.iloc[0].Area])
dec = False
for val, u in zip(df1.Area[1:], df1.u[1:]):
    ids.append(ids[-1] + (val not in seen) - dec)
    seen.add(val)
    dec = u == 0
df1['On'] = ids

df1 = df1.reindex(df.index).fillna(df1)
```

The problem is I want to run this script on all values in `Code`. Instead of selecting one at a time. For instance, if I want to do the same thing on `Code['B']`, I would have to change: `df2 = df1[df1.Code == 'B'].copy()` and the run the script again.

If I have numerous values in `Code` it becomes very inefficient. I need a `loop` where it finds all `unique` values in `'Code'`Ideally, the script would look like:

```
df1 = df[df.Code == 'All unique values'].copy()
```

Intended Output:

```
  Code   Area    u   On
0    A   Home  2.0  1.0
1    A   Work  1.0  2.0
2    A  Shops  0.0  3.0
3    A   Park  1.0  3.0
4    B   Cafe  1.0  1.0
5    A   Home  1.0  3.0
6    B   Cafe  0.0  1.0
7    A   Work  0.0  3.0
8    A   Home  0.0  2.0
9    A   Park  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `pd.unique`?

Comment: What's desired output?

Comment: @Julien. I don't need the total `unique` values in the `Column`. It's a bit more complex. It iterates through and determines the `unique` values that are 'currently' on. As in, if the appear later on the `df` they will be counted. If not they wont be. So `['u']` is how many times left will they appear. `['On']` is how many are going.

Comment: How many different Area values are there? Dozens?  Millions?

Comment: No more than 50. `Code` is generally between 5-15. But it can change which is the painful part. So it could be `ABCDEFGHI` one day and `ADEGHKLM` the next. If it was the same values in `Code` every time I would just run the script on those values.

Comment: This question is very confusing.  Can you just give us an example input data set and the expected output, with a brief English explanation of the meaning of the output?  What is the meaning of `'u'`?

Comment: @JohnZwinck is this any more clearer?

Comment: Your description for #2 doesn't seem complete, because it doesn't explain the final 2 and 1 (the `dec = u == 0` stuff).  Could you edit to explain exactly what "currently occurring" means?

Comment: @DSM, I've added a brief description on the first 4 indexes. I can add a full description if necessary. Mallor_l1 has the right idea but I'd like the df's to be combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your "On" logic very confusing.  That said, I think I can reproduce it:

```
df["u"] = df.groupby(["Code", "Area"]).cumcount(ascending=False)
df["nunique"] = pd.get_dummies(df.Area).groupby(df.Code).cummax().sum(axis=1)
df["On"] = (df["nunique"] - 
           (df["u"] == 0).groupby(df.Code).cumsum().groupby(df.Code).shift().fillna(0)
```

which gives me

```
In [212]: df
Out[212]: 
  Code   Area  u  nunique   On
0    A   Home  2        1  1.0
1    A   Work  1        2  2.0
2    A  Shops  0        3  3.0
3    A   Park  1        4  3.0
4    B   Cafe  1        1  1.0
5    A   Home  1        4  3.0
6    B   Cafe  0        1  1.0
7    A   Work  0        4  3.0
8    A   Home  0        4  2.0
9    A   Park  0        4  1.0
```

In this, `u` is the number of matching (Code, Area) pairs after that row.  nunique is the number of unique Area values seen so far in that Code.
On is the number of unique Areas seen so far, except that once we "run out" of an Area -- once it's not used any more -- we start subtracting it from nuniq.

Comment: Brilliant @DSM. This is a fair bit simpler. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

Using `GroupBy` with `size` and `cumcount`, you can construct your `u` series.

Your logic for `On` isn't clear: this requires clarification.

```
g = df.groupby(['Code', 'Area'])
df['u'] = g['Code'].transform('size') - (g.cumcount() + 1)

print(df)

  Code   Area  u
0    A   Home  2
1    A   Home  1
2    B  Shops  1
3    A   Park  1
4    B   Cafe  1
5    B  Shops  0
6    A   Home  0
7    B   Cafe  0
8    A   Work  0
9    A   Park  0
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've added some more insight and a brief description on the output. Is this any clearer?